# How we get sense of direction from faraday's law while it as a whole is scalar?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

I'm referring to Maxwell's third equation
If we assume direction of existing magnetic field i.e. M.F due to magnet as positive then if I look at Right hand side of equation which is $\frac{-d∅}{dt}$ then in direction sense it means that it will always give us the direction of induced emf or direction of induced current indirectly (if I take direction of induced emf as sense of rotation by right hand thumb rule).

Now if I consider Left hand side of equation also then I also have to take assumptions to slove left hand side for equation to hold true for induced emf like direction of dl is taken (by sense of right hand thumb rule) in the direction of existing magnetic field and if limits of integration goes from L1 to L2 then $L2>L1.$

Now if I consider negative sign on right hand side then it has a big role in defining the equation and for it to hold true considering all assumptions. Is that how negative sign is used and how it is related with Lenz law?

If we do not take negative sign on right hand side and take assumptions such that there is no need of negative sign for equation to hold true then we know the reality that induced emf is always in the direction in accordance with Lenz law. Now no negative sign is used then how can we say that negative sign signifies Lenz law as there is no negative sign and obviously reality is not changed equation always follows Lenz law.

I want to ask that are those assumptions responsible in defining what sign will signify?

Answer (score 0):

When we compute the flux $\phi_B=\iint \vec B \cdot \mathrm d\vec S$, we need a surface $S$ which has an orientation, i.e. a choice of normal vector at each point.

[image]

The boundary of an oriented surface inherits an orientation via the right-hand rule - specifically, if your thumb points in the direction of $\mathrm d\vec S$, your fingers curl in the direction of $\mathrm d\vec \ell$:

[image]

Faraday's law is often written in integral form as $\mathcal E \equiv \oint \vec E \cdot \mathrm d\vec \ell = -\frac{d}{dt}\phi_B$.  What this means is the following.  Consider any **oriented** surface you like, and compute the magnetic flux through that surface.  Next, compute the EMF $\mathcal E = \oint \vec E \cdot \mathrm d \vec \ell$ around the boundary of that surface, which inherits its own orientation via the right hand rule.  We then have that $\mathcal E = -\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$.

Specifically, let's choose the orientation of the surface as drawn in my figures, and say that $\frac{d\phi}{dt}>0$.  The minus sign in Faraday's law means that the induced EMF is oriented *opposite* to the blue arrows, i.e. the closed loop integral is negative.

Comment: Here dS is along magnetic field vector?

Comment: Is dS always along Direction of magnetic field?

Comment: @ManikSingh No,it has nothing to do with the magnetic field. It simply defines the orientation of the surface.

Comment: But how this negative sign tells us about Lenz law?

Comment: You said that - sign tells us that emf is induced in the opposite direction of dl but direction of dl is not fixed and it's our choice to give the hint of Lenz law it should dl should also have restrictions

Comment: @ManikSingh I’m afraid I don’t understand your question. That minus sign essentially *is* Lenz’s law- it tells you the direction of the induced EMF around the loop.

Comment: Sense of opposition is not particular for a particular case if we take dl as our choice and dl depends upon dS which is our choice

Comment: @ManikSingh As I explained in my answer, the choice of direction for $d\vec\ell$ is tied to your choice of direction for $d\vec S$. If you switch the direction of one, you switch the direction of the other, which is why it doesn’t matter what you choose.

Comment: Direction of E is fixed, rate of change of flux through  surface is also fixed it can be either positive or negative for a particular case and equation obviously is valid for all cases so it is also fixed then our choice lies only in choosing dS which indirectly means freedom to choose direction of dl. So, to satisfy the equation direction of dl should also be fixed?

Comment: @ManikSingh I don't understand what you're talking about.  The sign of $\phi_B$ depends on which direction you choose for $d\vec S$.  If you choose the opposite direction for $d\vec S$ (and therefore $d\vec \ell$), then you will have $\oint \vec E \cdot (\color{red}{-} d\vec \ell) = -\frac{d}{dt}(\color{red}{-} \phi_B)$, and the minus signs cancel out.

Comment: Oh! I forgot sorry

Comment: I have one more question if definition of magnetic flux is number of magnetic field lines passing perpendicular through an area then why we take negative flux

Comment: @ManikSingh The definition of magnetic flux is $\iint \vec B \cdot d\vec S$, which can be positive or negative.  The description in terms of magnetic field lines is an intuitive picture for elementary students to think about, but it's useless if you're actually calculating anything.  However, note that magnetic field lines are oriented as well. When a field line pokes through the surface in the direction of $d\vec S$, you can think of that as a positive contribution to the flux; when it pokes through the surface opposite to the direction of $d\vec S$, the contribution to the flux is negative.

Comment: So taking sign with flux is just for making it more useful and more generalised so that we can take into consideration different things while calculation , it's convenient to do like that.

Comment: "elementary students" that's me. I am in high school 12th grade.

Comment: How can we say that particularly negative sign is because of Lenz law? Can I think this in the way that if negative sign was not there?

Comment: @ManikSingh It's not a matter of convenience.  The definition of flux allows it to be positive or negative, full stop.  If a field line pokes through the surface and the direction of the line is in the same direction as $d\vec S$ at that point, then it makes a positive contribution to the flux.  If the direction of the line is opposite to the direction of $d\vec S$, then it makes a negative contribution to the flux.

Comment: @ManikSingh If the minus sign wasn't there, then the sign of the emf $\mathcal E$ would be different.  "Lenz's law" is the name given to the rule for figuring out the sign of $\mathcal E$, and is therefore equivalent to the presence of the minus sign $\mathcal E = \color{red}{-} \frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$ in Faraday's law.

Comment: If we consider only emf=-d∅/dt then freedom to choose orientation of surface will bring different signs of emf for same case what does that mean?

Comment: @ManikSingh EMF is calculated *along a path* (in this case, around a loop).  If you switch the direction of the loop, then you switch the direction of the EMF.  If you walk clockwise around a loop and compute a positive EMF, then if you walk **counter**clockwise around the loop you will compute a *negative* EMF.  Changing the orientation of the surface automatically changes the orientation of the loop, resulting in two minus signs which cancel each other out.

Comment: Why we take imaginary charge to move around loop to choose sign of emf in terms of work done by electric force?

Comment: @ManikSingh Comments are not for extended discussions, so I can't keep answering your questions here.  If you have new questions, you should ask them separately.  However, the definition of the EMF along a path is the total work per unit charge done by the electric field as you move along the path.  If you reverse the direction of the path, you reverse the sign of the EMF.

Comment: Last question:- What is the physical significance of negative sign in that equation? People say that negative sign has something to do with Lenz's law. I understood that negative sign is used to get correct sign of emf according to definition of emf. But how we can relate negative sign with Lenz's law definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124816/discussion-between-manik-singh-and-j-murray).